# Comparing Two Table Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, subquery

Another SQL question!

I have a couple of tables:

Employee has the following fields:

```
first name, last name, gender, ssn
```

Works_On has the following fields:

```
essn, pno
```

In Works_On, `essn` is a PK as well as `pno`. `pno` refers to a specific project number assigned to an employee, and `essn` is the social security number of that employee.

I'm tasked with finding out which employees work on projects in which the number of females working on said project exceed the number of males.

So far I've tried doing this with temporary tables, but have not received any output.

```
select e.lname, e.ssn, w.pno
from employee e left outer join works_on w
on e.ssn = w.essn, (select count(e1.ssn)
                from employee e1 left outer join works_on w1
                on e1.ssn = w1.essn
                where e1.sex = 'M') as Male(males), 

                (select count(e2.ssn)
                from employee e2 left outer join works_on w2
                on e2.ssn = w2.essn
                where e2.sex = 'F') as Females(females)
where females > males
```

I'm not sure that I'm doing the comparison right, and I think my temporary tables are picking up the wrong values.

Comment: Which database and server version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by finding out the gender breakdown of each project:

```
select w.pno, sum(case when e.sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as Males,
       sum(case when e.sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as Females
from employee e join
     works_on w
     on e.ssn = w.ess
group by w.pno;
```

Then join in the employee information and put in the condition:

```
select e.lname, e.ssn, w.pno
from employee e join
     works_on w
     on e.ssn = w.ess join
     (select w.pno, sum(case when e.sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as Males,
             sum(case when e.sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as Females
      from employee e join
           works_on w
           on e.ssn = w.ess
      group by w.pno
     ) g
     on w.pno = g.pno
where females > males;
```

That said, the easiest way is to use window functions:

```
select e.lname, e.ssn, w.pno
from (select w.pno,
             sum(case when e.sex = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by w.pno) as Males,
             sum(case when e.sex = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by w.pno) as Females
      from employee e join
           works_on w
           on e.ssn = w.ess
     ) g
where females > males;
```

Comment: Most of what you have makes sense to me, but I'm having trouble understanding why you're joining three separate tables. Also, why is it necessary to put names after the `sum(case when)` statements?

Comment: @mynorka . . . I don't understand your comment.  Your original query has two tables and two subqueries in the outer query, and each subquery consists of joining two tables -- more joins than in these queries.  However, none of them "join three separate tables"; two tables and a subquery to calculate the males and females.

Comment: You join `employee` and `works_on` and then join `works_on` and `g`?

Comment: @mynorka . . . I need the employee information and the project, so they need to be joined together.  Then, I need to select the gender information for the projects, so that comes from `g`.

Comment: `g` is not a table, it's a subquery